# Python - retrieving data from other classes

Tags: python

I have two classes whom I need to be able to talk to each other, mainly one taking data from the other. I omitted everything that was not needed.

```
class dog(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
    def getOwner(self):
        return self.name

class shelter(object):
    def getName(self,dogName):
        return dogName.getName()

doggy = dog("Rover")
animalHouse = shelter()

print animalHouse.getName("rover")
```

The only thing that returns is `AttributeError: 'shelter' object has no attribute 'getName'`

So how do I go about using the getName function from the dog class inside my shelter class?

Comment: you either want to put a `dog` in the `shelter` in the shelter's `__init__`, or make a `put` method to put one in there.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify the `getName` function. I think you want to declare `getName` instead of `getOwner` in the `dog` class there, and you need to pass the instance of `dog` to the function.

```
class dog(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
    def getOwner(self):
        return self.name

class shelter(object):
    def getName(self,dogName):
        return dogName.getOwner()

doggy = dog("Rover")
animalHouse = shelter()
```

And finally:

```
#Pass the instance!
print animalHouse.getName(doggy)
```

Comment: A copying error? That means you didn't copy it.. Copy the actual code, or else i can't help you..

Answer (score 0):

Your approach really isn't OOP.  What's the point of `shelter`?  You could just invoke `getOwner` directly on the `doggy` instance. Think about the physical realities of the objects you're dealing with.  You have a `dog` and a `shelter`.  How does the shelter interact with the dog?

The easiest way is to put one in there.  So write that method.  Let's give your shelter a `resident` attribute:

```
def put(self,dog):
   self.resident = dog
```

Now, it's best to have your `shelter` always have that attribute defined, so let's do that in the initializer:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.resident = None
```

And while we're at it, let's give ourselves the ability to specify the resident at the time when we create the shelter:

```
def __init__(self,dog=None):
    self.resident = dog
```

This is making use of the "default attribute" feature of python.  You can specify that argument, or not; it defaults to `None` if you don't.  If this is confusing, you can skip this step.

---

Given all that (and having `put` a `dog` in there), now we have a `shelter` that contains `None` or a `dog`.  Let's write your `getName` method now.

```
def getName(self):
    if self.resident:
        return self.resident.getOwner() #this method is questionably named, but you wrote it
    else:
        return 'nobody home!'
```

Other comments: your classes should be named starting with Uppercase letters, and your methods should favor underscores to separate words as opposed to using mixedCase.  So `Shelter` for the class, and `get_name` for the method.  This is according to python naming conventions, see PEP 8 for all the gory details.  :)

Comment: This was for an assignment haha. Thanks for all that info, I'll definitely use it when it's not specified by the professor